# When I try deploying my CloudFormation template I get "The availability zones of the specified subnets and the AutoScalingGroup do not match"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template I'm trying to deploy.

It was made for **us-west-2**. I'm trying to deploy it in **us-east-1**.

I've tried making all the changes required, but I keep getting a **error**:

> CREATE_FAILED

**around:**

> Type:AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup    Logical ID:
>   WebServerScalingGroup  Reason: The availability zones of the specified
>   subnets and the AutoScalingGroup do not match

Below is part of my template referencing "`WebServerScalingGroup`".

```
"WebServerScalingGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "UpdatePolicy":{
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate":{
          "MinInstancesInService":{
            "Ref":"MinWebServers"
          },
          "MaxBatchSize":"1",
          "PauseTime":"PT5M"
        }
      },
      "Properties":{
        "AvailabilityZones":{
          "Fn::FindInMap":[
            "AWSRegions2AZ",
            {
              "Ref":"Region"
            },
            "AZ"
          ]
        },
        "VPCZoneIdentifier":{
          "Ref":"WebServerSubnetsID"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName":{
          "Ref":"WebServerLaunchConfig"
        },
        "MinSize":{
          "Ref":"MinWebServers"
        },
        "MaxSize":{
          "Ref":"MaxWebServers"
        },
        "DesiredCapacity":{
          "Ref":"DesiredNumberOfWebServers"
        },
        "LoadBalancerNames":[
          {
            "Ref":"ElasticLoadBalancer"
          }
        ],
        "Tags":[
          {
            "Key":"Network",
            "Value":"Private",
            "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"
          },
          {
            "Key":"Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join":[
                    "",
                    [
                      "vidly-mediadrop-app-",
                      {
                        "Ref":"EnvironmentType"
                      }
                    ]
              ]
            },
            "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

**EDIT:** Below is `AWSRegions2AZ`

```
"AWSRegions2AZ":{
      "us-east-1":{
        "AZ":[
          "us-east-1b",
          "us-east-1c",
          "us-east-1d",
          "us-east-1e"
        ]
      }
```

Comment: you need to show us the `AWSRegions2AZ` map and your parameter values.

Comment: @tedder42 I added it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from the snippets you have provided but from the message you are getting, I would say that the subnet ID's you are providing in `WebServerSubnetsID` are associated with a different set (or subset of) the availability zones returned by `AWSRegions2AZ`.

Do you have a subnet created in each of those AZ's?

Comment: Generally speaking, I suspect the problem can be solved by simply removing the `AvailabilityZones`, since the list of `VPCZoneIdentifier`s is a superset of it.